# ansible module mongodb_user produces "not authorized for insert on dname.system.users"

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I'm trying to add a user to a mongodb database via ansible using the "mongodb_user" module.

The exact configuration (actual usernames and passwords switched out, of course) I am using is:

```
- name: set up mongodb credentials
  mongodb_user: name=new_db_user password=user_pwd database=mydb roles='readWrite' state=present login_user=admin login_password=admin_pwd login_database=admin
```

The result (using `-vvvv`) I am getting is this, however (output formatted for readability):

```
fatal: [some.host.net]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
  "failed": true,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "database": "mydb",
      "login_database": "admin",
      "login_host": "localhost",
      "login_password": "admin_pwd",
      "login_port": "27017",
      "login_user": "admin",
      "name": "new_db_user",
      "password": "user_pwd",
      "replica_set": null,
      "roles": [
        "readWrite"
      ],
      "ssl": false,
      "state": "present",
      "update_password": "always"
    },
    "module_name": "mongodb_user"
  },
  "msg": "not authorized for insert on mydb.system.users"
}
```

While this looks like a simple permission issue, it unfortunately doesn't seem to be. The admin user I am using has the `root` role, and performing the exact same operation (using the exact same credentials) directly via the commandline on the remote machine adds the user without issue:

```
[root@somehost etc]# mongo admin -u admin -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
Enter password: 
connecting to: admin
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.createUser({user: 'new_db_user', pwd: 'user_pwd', roles: ['readWrite']})
Successfully added user: { "user" : "new_db_user", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
```

I've checked, double checked and triple checked all usernames and passwords, and they're definitely correct. Changing databases or usernames produces the same error as well.

edit: Additionally, I tried setting the admin user's role to "userAdminAnyDatabase", as well as "userAdmin" and combine that with various other administrative roles, the result was the exact same each time, however. Thanks to Raul Hugo for pointing this out.

I am using ansible 2.0 (same error with ansible 1.9), mongodb version is 2.6.9 running on RHEL 7.1.

Comment: Maybe, you could try with a user with **userAdmin** role instead root role.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that in my original question, I'll edit the info into it for clarity: I tried using not onyl the "root" role, but also various combinations of "userAdmin" and "userAdminAnyDatabase" in combination with various other administrative roles, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying  to reproduce the issue without success.

```
ansible -i hosts mongo --user vagrant -k -m  name=new_db_user -m mongodb_user -a "name=new_db_user password=user_pwd database=mydb roles='readWrite' state=present login_user=admin1 login_password=admin_pwd1 login_database=admin"
SSH password:
local | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
    "user": "new_db_user"
}
```

But the problem **is the version of the auth algorithm on MongoDB**, the last pymongo library uses **SCRAM-SHA algoritm**, and MongoDB 2.6 uses **MONGO-CR** by default. That is the reason for the problem.

You could upgrade your Mongodb Version or change your auth algoritm on 2.6.  You could find information about the process here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - this will be the first thing I'll be looking into tomorrow, I'll let you know if it solves my problem - it does sound very promising.

Comment: Alright, that sort of solved the problem. I upgraded the auth schema on the target machine - however, after this I **also** had to grant the admin user the `userAdminAnyDatabase` role (in addition to `root`, which, to me, is rather counterintuitive) for it to finally work via ansible. Interestingly enough, the admin user was able to create and drop the user from the target database via commandline even without the `userAdminAnyDatabase` role.